# Inline_svg gem not working. SVG file not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, svg, inline-svg

I'm running rails 5.0.1 and using last version of inline_svg gem : [Inline SVG](https://github.com/jamesmartin/inline_svg)

The issue is that even if I put my svg with the right path like this :

```
<%= inline_svg "/assets/svg/add.svg", class: 'some-class' %>
```

And the image is located in "app/assets/svg/add.svg".

I get this error on the browser :

```
<!-- SVG file not found: '/assets/svg/add.svg' -->
```

I think he could because svg are not correctly load by rails but I didn't see any information on that on google.

Comment: Could be that app/assets/svg is not part of the assets pipeline. Open a rails console and type in Rails.application.assets.paths. This will show the directories the asset pipeline accesses. If app/assets/svg is not listed, then add it.

Comment: I did check that and app/assets/svg is on the list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<%= inline_svg 'add.svg' %>`

Your svg can be found at `localhost:3000/assets/add.svg`

you said that you already checked the path, but If you need additional proof run `rails c` then `Rails.application.config.assets.paths`

Your path should be in the output

### Asset is not precompiled

If you can not display the asset at `localhost:3000/assets/add.svg`, it means it was not precompiled. This procedure takes the files from some folders (like `app/assets/javascript` and `stylesheets`, etc..) and the folders you included in the `application.rb` or `assets.rb` file with

```
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app","assets", "svg")
```

and creates for every required file a fingerprinted version. The fingerprint is an alpha-numberic code that distinguish every different version of your `application.js`, `scss` and your pictures other files [read more at about fingerprinting hear](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#what-is-fingerprinting-and-why-should-i-care-questionmark)

Also you can precompile development or production, but you have 2 different commands, so the question is **where do you experience this problem?**

If you are precompiling in development, you can then `git add <name-of-new-files-precompiled>` then `git status` to check that the new file/svg was added to your git before running `git commit -m 'adding an svg file to git'` then run `git push heroku master` or `git push -u origin master`

### Other Scenarios

I wait for your input, first thing I need to know is if you can display  that asset in production/development

Also what version of the gem you are using, because only version 0.10 supports rails 5. Maybe rails 5.0.1 is not supported.

Also read this issue about supporting [absolute file paths](https://github.com/jamesmartin/inline_svg/issues/70)

Answer (score 1):

It will work if you just store the SVGs in `app/assets/images/svg` and call `<%= image_tag 'svg/add.svg' %>`